# Макрос vba. Вставка в формулу пути к файлу с текущей датой

Tags: excel, vba

Есть файл в котором несколько листов, на первом листе таблица с данными, в этой таблице есть формула ВПР, которая берет данные из таблицы другого файла. Другой файл переодически обновляется и имеет название файла "отчет 01.01.2019" (файл с новой датой переодически кладет другой человек в ту же папку).
Можно ли сделать макрос который при запуске исходного файла изменял в формуле дату на текущую (в пути к файлу)? при этом возможно ли чтобы при отсутствии файла с текущей датой брался файл предыдущий? (например, если тек.дата - нет, смотрим тек.дата -1 день - нет, тек.дата -2 - есть)

В исходном файле много данных, формул, макросов, полноценный пример сложно предоставить
ссылка на файлик примера
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LfaT/hYT7gCaAr

Comment: Сначала можно понять, что две таблицы в одном файле, оказывается -  два файла? Название таблицы - это умная таблица (имеет имя, именованный диапазон) или название написано над таблицей? Или Вы подразумевали название файла? В файле-источнике данных один лист или несколько? Опишите нормально. покажите пример расположения данных

Comment: Два файла, да, не дописал. Название файла я подразумевал, в папку переодически кладется файл отчета сделанного текущим днем. В файле-источнике несколько листов, но формула использует один. Пример, не нашел как приложить файл..

Comment: Так допишите нормально и покажите примеры. Не вытягивать же из Вас информацию по крупинкам...

Comment: пытался так и сделать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем формула, если все равно используется *VBA*? Тянуть данные макросом:

```
Sub DataShop()
Dim aData(), aShop(), aRes()
Dim sPath As String, dDate As Date, bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Const sFolder As String = "I:\путькфайлу\"
Const lRwStart As Long = 5 ' начало диапазона'
    With ActiveSheet
        i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        If i < 5 Then Exit Sub
        aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 3).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value 
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To UBound(aShop), 1 To 1)
    dDate = Date

    Do
        sPath = sFolder & "отчет (" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ").xls"
        If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then bFlag = True: Exit Do  ' файл найден'
        dDate = dDate - 1 ' если не найден, уменьшаем дату для следующего имени файла'
    Loop Until dDate = Date - 5 ' просматриваем максимум 5 файлов (5 дат)'

    If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Нет файла-донора", 64, "ОШИБКА": GoTo err_

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
        With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
            i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
            aData = .Range("B1:K" & i).Value
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 10) ' записываем найденное'
        Next i
    Next k

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(lRwStart - 1, 6).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, 6).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
err_:
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Если обработка не на активном листе - в двух местах кода заменить *ActiveSheet* на *Worksheet("имя файла")*

Код разместить в общем модуле, запуск вручную или кнопкой.

Для автообновления данных код запустить при открытии файла. В модуле книги:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call DataShop
End Sub
```

Comment: Как-то сложно для меня оказалось адаптировать под мой файлик макрос.. Первое это я забыл указать, что в файле доноре не на первом листе данные :( лист называется "по филиалам". "With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'" - тут нужно поправить название листа?

Comment: Да, измените ссылку на лист: *Worksheets("по филиалам")*

Comment: дальше не могу понять, куда полученные данные из донора попадают в основной файлик? впр был понятен, с переменными сложнее) в основном файле столбец начиная с AS12 (до AS113) имеет формулу ВПР, которая ищет значение из A12 (до A113) в доноре (в первом столбце) и при найденных данных берет значение из той же строки 10го столбца. А где в макросе абзац об этом же?:/

Comment: В конце смотрите строку с комментарием "выгрузка на лист". Начиная с ячейки *.Cells(lRwStart, 6)* (строка из переменной, 6 столбец). Размер диапазона вставки *Resize(UBound(aRes), 1)* - строк столько, сколько в вертикальной размерности массива, 1 столбец.

Comment: *aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 3).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value* - данные  столбца С (третьего) из текущего листа. *aData = .Range("B1:K" & i).Value* - этот диапазон из донора. в цикле с k : *If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 10)* - если значение строки из *aShop* совпало со значением  из первого столбца массива (в массиве первый соответствует столбцу В листа), то в результат записываем значение столбца 10 ( в массиве  10 соответствует столбцу К листа)

Comment: извиняюсь, не хватает времени разобраться. Вновь не выходит у меня..  With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(lRwStart - 12, 45).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, 45).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист' Поправил тут 6ку на 45, так как формула =столбец сказала, что там где у меня данные это 45й столбец.. макрос работает и вставляет данные, но в весь столбец с 1й строкии там где надо пусто... подумал, что он смотрит не на тот столбец, так как впр смотрел на столбец А, то есть 1й.  aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value изменил 3 на 1

Comment: (номер столбца как понял) и теперь строка .Cells(lRwStart - 12, 45).Value = dDate ' дата  файла' выделяется желтым) боюсь для меня это будет слишком сложно)

Comment: В начале макроса задана константа *lRwStart = 5*. Вы сделали  *lRwStart - 12* = -7 Естествено, что номера строки с отрицательным значением не существует.

Comment: если можно еще вопрос. С диапазоном разобрался. Но при запуске макроса вставляется только часть данных, по какому принципу не знаю, часть вставилось, часть осталось пустое. Что может быть не так? в доноре есть соотв данные..

Comment: Без пациента - лечение сложной болезни по телефону.

Comment: Залить примеры файлов на какой-либо файлообменник? или тут макрос сплошным текстом вставлять?

Comment: лучше показать файл

Comment: пока делал пример понял в чем проблема, учитывает регистр ячеек, в доноре все написано с заглавной буквы, в основе что-то с заглавной, что-то с строчной. Как-то можно убрать требования к регистру?

Comment: примените `UCase` или `LCase`

Comment: хотел в макрос вставить изменение регистра, как обычно сложно) просто в основном файле формулой изменил все на с заглавной, спасибо. И еще вопрос возник, как ограничить макрос строкой №120, например? макрос идет дальше, там и строки с 0 значениями находит и вставляет ниже таблицы какие-то данные и ниже какое-то значение совпало с таблицей, тоже вставилось что-то)

Comment: В самом начале определяется размер используемого диапазона -переменная i. Задайте *i=120*

Comment: спасибо. Вновь косяк возник, в основном файле диапазон в ширину переодически меняется (кол-во столбцов) и получается что макрос вставляет в не верный столбец.. Возможно ли какую-то доработку придумать, чтобы макрос находил в строке 11 ячейку с текстом "за день" и принимал этот столбец за нужный? With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(lRwStart, 45).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, 45).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист' - сейчас это "45"

Comment: Вы все вопросы к одному... Растянестя до невозможности. Понятно, что Ваша задача одна, но вопросы-то разные по тематике. Вопросы не по теме следует задавать отдельно.

Comment: понял, спасибо. да понимаю, что долгий нудный процесс...